# Data Studio | Date Filter | Greater than Today

Tags: looker-studio

I have a DATE field and would like to filter anything above today's date, is that possible in Data Studio?

Example Dates:
'02-04-2020',
'02-05-2020',
'02-06-2020',
'03-20-2020'

Today's date: 
'03-06-2020'

When I filter in data studio, I only want 03-20-2020 to be returned

What is available for me to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved using a [Date Range Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067) and setting the *Date Range* to *Advanced*; for example, to set the *Date Range* to dynamically capture the period between *Today* and *Today Plus 999 Days*:

```
Start Date: Today Minus 0 Day(s)
End Date: Today Plus 999 Day(s)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/94e42c0f-c36f-4275-b7bd-fb21bb6bd167) to demonstrate, as well as a GIF showing the process:

[image: 3]]